# Microsoft Graph API for Email: Email ID is not unique

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, uniqueidentifier

I'm find that that the "id" column for Email from the Graph API does not seem to be unique i.e. once saved to a SQL Server DB

This appears to be due to collation issues; I tried applying COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, but duplicates persisted

I then tried applying the Collation to the table - I did not want to apply a change of Collation to the whole DB - so far, this seems to do it

But I'd also like to know how to apply Collation to SQL statements; so far, I applied it to SELECT and JOIN, but - per above - this was (apparently) insufficient ... documentation on this seems lacking ...

Comment: In your case ids are not same. They differ at the end `..BAAAA=` vs `..BaAAA=`. What is important to know that message id is not immutable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I had just noticed myself; I have now revised the question, which now to do with detail of Collation; but immutable is relevant too ...